# Keycloak JS frontend, pass auth to subdomain and new window/tab

Tags: authorization, keycloak, web-frontend

I have a somewhat complex React/Redux single page web app, and a Keycloak-protected backend. Using the Keycloak-JS-adapter I can login, and by passing on the auth token to request headers I can query the backend's protected API and resources, everything works like a charm. But there are some other requirements:

[image: Connection of protected services]

The webapp can use frontend services (1) (which, for simplicity's sake, are displayed in an iframe and served from a subdomain of the app). These might in turn need to do API requests (3) or display resources (5).
It would be nice if she frontend's auth could be shared, so the services would not need to do auth- and token-management on their own, thus also sparing me from creating configurations for each service in Keycloak, especially as all permissions are user-specific, not service-specific.

The webapp (and maybe some frontend service) might want to open files directly in new tabs (2, 4). Due to file size, reading in files as blobs and piping them into a new window is not an option.

I feel like being able to make Keycloak store the tokens as a cookie would solve all my problems. Then the services would share the login info, as it is on a subdomain, and opening resources in new windows would work too, as long as the cookie is still present. However, simply enabling the Keycloak session iframe would not solve the problem, as the iframe's cookies are not passed on with requests.

Is there some misconception on my side? Is there a better way to achieve my goal using Keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, authentication should not be handled in the frontend, but rather in the frontend's server.

Using `keycloak-connect` and `express-session` middlewares in my `node` server will do the following:

- Redirect any users that ar not logged in to keycloak, log in and redirect back (standard browser flow)
- Set a `connection.sid` cookie that identifies a browser with a login session. This cookie will, of  course, be sent with all requests sent to the frontend server, be it inside a frontend session or just requesting some frontend resources in a new window, and it will be valid as long as the user is logged in.
- In addition, this way the whole access token stays hidden from the user agent, adding another layer of security
- Also, the frontend app does not even need to know it's protected by keycloak, allowing to change deployment easily or skip authentication for local dev versions

Of course the solution is valid for any tools and adapters, not just the `node` way. Just manage the log in session in the backend. If you need additional user information, like the username etc., you can create a convenience endpoint for that in the backend...